# User Login using a JSON file

Tags: java, json

I am attempting to create a User Login program where the existing username's and password's are stored in a JSON file, but I am having trouble retrieving the usernames and passwords from the file for comparison. My JSON file is set up as such:

> [{
> "username": "robert",
> "password_hash": "2d559ca435bbe90d965492bf8187243d6a611e6fece6e7467f4a0a1cfdd91879"
> },
> {
> "username": "john",
> "password_hash": "1fefaaaceda5a7e199e2c612ca6716d6da8065eed5a1a50979a309f27797e01f"
> },
> {
> "username": "juan"  ,
> "password_hash": "965701cd196ff52123c759efeb9821d5f08d2647a912577bf5aa4aaf58cf75be"
> },
> {
> "username": "annie"  ,
> "password_hash": "ccdb84ebe2a9bc6894fd2f441ea56cb5a51e76737a1067e1e9a00bdee6896e64"
> },
> {
> "username": "jackie"  ,
> "password_hash": "26ff6fed929876a8c83dd8f548bcb97aeadf5dace7d67849fc144420f41177ce"
> }
> ]

My code that I have set up as a test goes as such:

```
public static void credentialCheck(String existingUsername, String sha256hexEntrdPaswrd){ 
        
        //Checks Validity of User's Credentials
        boolean validUser = false;
        
        JSONArray userArray = new JSONArray();
        Object ob = null;
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        
        
        try {
            FileReader file = new FileReader("JSONUserLoginProject.json");
            ob = jsonParser.parse(file);
            userArray = (JSONArray) ob;
            System.out.println(userArray.get(1));
            file.close();
        } //end try-block
        catch(FileNotFoundException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(ParseException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

Which gives me the following output when entering a username and password:

> {"password_hash":"1fefaaaceda5a7e199e2c612ca6716d6da8065eed5a1a50979a309f27797e01f","username":"john"}

I would however like to retrieve the username and password individually using something conceptually similar to

> System.out.println(userArray.get("Username") output: john
> and
> System.out.println(userArray.get("password_hash") output: 26ff6fed929876a8c83dd8f548bcb97aeadf5dace7d67849fc144420f41177ce

But of course with code that is actually correct.

Comment: What is your issue ?

Comment: My mistake. I have edited the original post.

Comment: Arrays are indexed, ordered containers. You can't instantly locate things in them by value. If you want to do that, you need to use a JSON object, not an array. So your JSON file will need to be formatted as `{"john": { "password_hash": "..." }, "annie": { "password_hash": "..." }}`

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do, won't work, since the JSON array contains objects and not key, value items.

The quickest and best way to get around this would be creating a Java `Class` which contains the data you need.

```java
public class UserData
{
    private String username;
    private String passwordHash;
    
    // Constructors, getters, setters
}
```

Then reading your data into an array of `UserData` objects.

```java
List<UserData> listWithUsers = new ArrayList<>(); // Creating the list with users
for (int i = 0 ; i < userArray.length(); i++) // iterating over each JSON object in your array
{
    JSONObject userJsonObject = userArray.getJSONObject(i);
    UserData currUser = new UserData();
    currUser.setUsername(userJsonObject.get("username")); // Getting the username From the Json object
    currUser.setPasswordHash(userJsonObject.get("password_hash")); // Same thing for passwordHash
    
    listWithUsers.add(currUser);
}
```

Then the most important step, when the user tries to login, you can `filter` this list and see whether this list contains a user with the `username` specified.
Example:

```java
String usernameOfUserTryingToLogIn = "John".toLowerCase();
Optional<String> foundUserOptional = listWithUsers.stream().filter(userData -> userData.getUsername().equals(usernameOfUserTryingToLogIn)).findFirst();

if(foundUserOptional.isPresent())
{
    // User is found, do what you need to do with his password
    UserData foundUser = foundUserOptional.get();
}
else
{
    // User not found, means he is not registered or whatever you want to do ...
}
```

Yet another suggestion, do not read the file every time the user tries to log in, read the file only the first time when you launch the program and save your data in a list as described above. That is of course if the file does not change externally.

Comment: we can implement file watcher service for that file and reload the content on update event is triggered

Comment: That's an even better Idea @silentsudo ,I have never done that before. Do you have any resources where I can read a bit about it? Thanks